# Aggregate R (absolute) difference

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
structure(list(from = c("China", "China", "Canada", "Canada", 
"USA", "China", "Trinidad and Tobago", "China", "USA", "USA"), 
    to = c("Japan", "Japan", "USA", "USA", "Japan", "USA", "USA", 
    "Rep. of Korea", "Canada", "Japan"), weight = c(4766781396, 
    4039683737, 3419468319, 3216051707, 2535151299, 2513604035, 
    2303474559, 2096033823, 2091906420, 2066357443)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    from = c("Canada", "China", "China", "China", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
    "USA", "USA"), to = c("USA", "Japan", "Rep. of Korea", "USA", 
    "USA", "Canada", "Japan"), .rows = structure(list(3:4, 1:2, 
        8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, c(5L, 10L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I would like to perform the absolute value of difference in `weight` column grouped by `from` and `to`.

I'm trying with the function `aggregate()` but it seems to work for means and sums and not for difference. For example (`df` is the name of my `dataframe`):

```
aggregate(weight~from+to, data = df, FUN=mean)
```

which produces:

```
                 from            to     weight
1                 USA        Canada 2091906420
2               China         Japan 4403232567
3                 USA         Japan 2300754371
4               China Rep. of Korea 2096033823
5              Canada           USA 3317760013
6               China           USA 2513604035
7 Trinidad and Tobago           USA 2303474559
```

**EDIT.** The desired result is instead

```
                 from            to     weight
1                 USA        Canada 2091906420
2               China         Japan 727097659
3                 USA         Japan 468793856
4               China Rep. of Korea 2096033823
5              Canada           USA 203416612
6               China           USA 2513604035
7 Trinidad and Tobago           USA 2303474559
```

As we can see, the countries that appear two times in the columns `from` and `to` colllapsed in only one row with the difference between weights in the column `weight`. E.g.,

```
from            to            weight
China           Japan         4766781396
China           Japan         4039683737
```

become

```
from            to            weight
China           Japan         727097659
```

because

```
> 4766781396-4039683737
[1] 727097659
```

The difference should be positive (and this is why I wrote "the absolute value of difference of the weights").

The couples of countries which instead appear just in one row of dataframe `df` remain the same, as e.g.

```
                 from            to     weight
7 Trinidad and Tobago           USA 2303474559
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `the absolute value of difference in weight`, what is the formula?

Comment: Or you can include a few lines of your expected output to clarify

Comment: @benson23: I'm sorry, I edited my post

Comment: So the assumption is that there will be at most 2 records per group? And if so you want to subtract the second value from the first, and the order is important?

Comment: @user2974951, the order is not important, for the other questions the answer is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming at most 2 values per group and that the order of the difference is not important

```
aggregate(weight~from+to, data=df, FUN=function(x){
  abs(ifelse(length(x)==1,x,diff(x)))
})

                 from            to     weight
1                 USA        Canada 2091906420
2               China         Japan  727097659
3                 USA         Japan  468793856
4               China Rep. of Korea 2096033823
5              Canada           USA  203416612
6               China           USA 2513604035
7 Trinidad and Tobago           USA 2303474559
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you are looking for?

```r
f <- function(x) abs(x[2] - x[1])
aggregate(weight ~ from + to, data = df, FUN = f)

#>                  from            to    weight
#> 1                 USA        Canada        NA
#> 2               China         Japan 727097659
#> 3                 USA         Japan 468793856
#> 4               China Rep. of Korea        NA
#> 5              Canada           USA 203416612
#> 6               China           USA        NA
#> 7 Trinidad and Tobago           USA        NA
```